# React: Unselect all radio buttons via button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that renders three **custom** radio buttons. The user can either submit the selected or clear (unselect) them, leaving with no selected radio buttons.

I tried some options with comparing the `filterResult` to the `data.value`, but without success. Here's a simplified code:

```
// imports
...

type Props = {
  filterConfig: PropTypes.object,
  filterValue: Proptypes.string,
  onFilterChange: PropTypes.func
}

class Filter extends React.Component {
  this.props = Props
  this.state = {
    filterValue: this.props.filterValue,
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ filterValue: e.target.value })
  }

  handleSubmit = () => {
    this.props.onFilterChange(this.state.filterValue)
    this.refs.filterContainer.close()
  }

  handleClear = () => {
    this.setState({ filterValue: '' })
  }

  renderOptions = () => {
    const { data, name } = this.props.filterConfig
    const options = data.map(
      (o, i) => (
        <div className='custom-radio' key={i}>
          <input
            id={`${name}-${i}`}
            name={name}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            type='radio'
            value={o.value}
          />
          <label htmlFor={`${name}-${i}`}>
            <span />
            {o.label}
          </label>
        </div>
      )
    )

    return (
      <div>
        {options}
      </div>
    )
  }

  renderPickerNavigation = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <a
          href='javascript:void(0)'
          onClick={this.handleClear}
        >
          Clear
        </a>
        <a
          href='javascript:void(0)'
          onClick={this.handleSubmit}
        >
          Done
        </a>
      </div>
    )
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <FilterWrapper
        ref='filterWrapper'
      >
        {this.renderOptions()}
        {this.renderPickerNavigation()}
      </FilterWrapper>
    )
  }
}
```

The data I'm passing in is:

```
const filters = [
  {
    data: [{
      label: 'Label 1',
      value: 1
    }, {
      label: 'Label 2',
      value: 2
    }, {
      label: 'Label 3',
      value: 3
    }],
    name: 'userFilter'
  }
]
```

EDIT: The click event on the native radio input works fine, so no need to change that to be on the custom radio (the `span` element) or the label.

Comment: What behavior are you expecting? Note that your event handlers are not defined correctly. (they need to be written like `this.change = () => {...}` or explicitly bound)

Comment: I will change that to be correct, we use our own private library that doesn't require that syntax. But what I need to know is how to make the selected radio button unselected via `clear` method called on button click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should begin with having a state variable that stores which radio is currently selected. The initial value for this should be `null` (or some other falsy value) if you want none to be pre-selected.

The reset button should trigger a function which resets this state variable back to the initial value.

---

Take a look at this simple demo, using **custom css radio buttons** as you requested:

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedRadio: null,
      products: [{id: 1, name: "foo"}, {id: 2, name: "bar"}, {id: 3, name: "baz"}]
    }
  }
  
  select = (id) => {
    this.setState({selectedRadio: id});
  }
  
  reset = () => {
    this.setState({selectedRadio: null});
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.products.map(
          (item) => {
            return (
              <div key={item.id}>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio" checked={this.state.selectedRadio === item.id} />
                <label onClick={this.select.bind(this, item.id)}>{item.name}<span /></label>
              </div>
            );
          }
        )}
        <button onClick={this.reset}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]+label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 34%;
}

input[type="radio"]+label span {
  background-color: #333;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label span {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

***Note:*** Since you are hiding the input element with css, you cannot have any listeners on it (e.g `onChange` or `onClick`). Instead, you should have `onClick` on the `span` that replaces it (see code below).

---

For a solution of how to reset all **"traditional", non-css-only radio buttons**, see the snippet below:

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedRadio: null,
      products: [{id: 1, name: "foo"}, {id: 2, name: "bar"}, {id: 3, name: "baz"}]
    }
  }
  
  select = (id) => {
    this.setState({selectedRadio: id});
  }
  
  reset = () => {
    this.setState({selectedRadio: null});
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.products.map(
          (item) => {
            return (
              <div key={item.id}>
                <label>{item.name}</label>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio" onChange={this.select.bind(this, item.id)} checked={this.state.selectedRadio === item.id} />
              </div>
            );
          }
        )}
        <button onClick={this.reset}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: That's a good idea, the only problem is my object doesn't have an ID. So I tried using the value instead and add `checked={this.state.filterResult === e.value}`. For some reason though, the `this.state.filterResult` is always empty within the map function, but outside of it is populated with the new value and the result of that is the radio is not selected at all.

Comment: @abpetkov, can you add the full code for the component? I can see you have cut certain things out, but right now it looks like your state declaration isn't inside the constructor, which I can't tell if that's intentional or because you cut code out.

Comment: Also, you should avoid using the letter `e` as the variable name for the current item in a loop, since that's typically used for events. While it will work, it might be confusing to others. Also, there is no reason to have a `value` here, your state variable already knows which item is selected, so you could just look it up in your `data`. Also, you could use `label` as an `id`. It seems unique, and so that could work as an identifier.

Comment: updated the original post with more detailed code. Please LMK if you have a different suggestion.

Comment: @abpetkov, change `onChange={this.handleChange}` to `onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)}`. In `handleChange` do instead: `handleChange = (id) => { this.setState({ filterValue: id }) }` and then for `checked` do: `checked={this.state.filterValue === i}` and that should work. To reset all, just set `filterValue` to `null`.

Comment: I see what you're doing and I know it should be working. For some reason when setting the conditional statement in the `checked` property, the radio buttons stops getting selected on click. I'm trying to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @abpetkov, can you post a **new** question, and then post the link to it here? Comments are getting too long, and the issue is no longer really about resetting all radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This example can help you https://codepen.io/evoyan/pen/vxGBOw

Code:

```
class Radio extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {selected: false};
  }

  toggle() {
    const {onChange} = this.context.radioGroup;
    const selected = !this.state.selected;
    this.setState({selected});
    onChange(selected, this);
  }

  setSelected(selected) {
    this.setState({selected});
  }

  render() {
    let classname = this.state.selected ? 'active' : ''
    return (
      <button type="button" className={classname} onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}>
        {this.state.selected ? 'yes' : 'no'}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

Radio.contextTypes = {
  radioGroup: React.PropTypes.object
};

class RadioGroup extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.options = [];
  }

  getChildContext() {
    const {name} = this.props;
    return {radioGroup: {
      name,
      onChange: this.onChange.bind(this)
    }};
  }

  onChange(selected, child) {
    this.options.forEach(option => {
      if (option !== child) {
        option.setSelected(!selected);
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    let children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        ref: (component => {this.options.push(component);}) 
      });
    });
    return <div className="radio-group">{children}</div>;
  }
}

RadioGroup.childContextTypes = {
  radioGroup: React.PropTypes.object
};

class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <RadioGroup name="test">
        <Radio value="1" />
        <Radio value="2" />
        <Radio value="3" />
      </RadioGroup>
    );
  }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```